# The meaning of a few things in a batch command

Tags: windows, command-line, registry

I'm looking for good tutorials to learn programming batch and it looks simple enough but I cant seem to find information on what /v, /t , /d represent...

I assume:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun"   /v "1" /t REG_SZ /d "msnmsgr.exe" /f

/v = value
/t = target
/d = ?
/f = ?
```

Am I correct on v and t? and what about d & f

Comment: Those aren't "batch parameters" those are parameters specific to the `reg` command. type `reg /?` and you'll get a short help (or for the above command use `reg add /?`

Comment: We don't do "links to tutorials" here. In fact, they're specifically mentioned as off-topic in the [help/on-topic] - see item #5 in the list. Links to tutorials would be an "off-site resource".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with batch commands. Those are command-line options to the [reg.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) executable.

```
reg add <KeyName> [{/v ValueName | /ve}] [/t DataType] [/s Separator] [/d Data] [/f]
```

If you're interested in command-line utilities that are part of Windows, you should bookmark the [TechNet A-Z List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)